# Question on real analysis...

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose $(X, \mathcal{F}_1, P_1)$ and $(Y, \mathcal{F}_2,P_2)$ are two measure spaces. My teacher taught us that the way to define a $\sigma-$field on $X \times Y$, we can consider the $\sigma-$field generated by rectangles:

$$ \mathcal{R} = \{ A_1 \times A_2 : A_1 \in \mathcal{F}_1, \; \; A_2 \in \mathcal{F}_2\}$$
and denoted this product $\sigma-$field by $\mathcal{F}_1 \times \mathcal{F}_2$.

Then this product sigma field is also generated by cylinders

$$ \mathcal{C} = \{A_1 \times Y : A_1 \in \mathcal{F}_1\} \cup \{X \times A_2 : A_2 \in \mathcal{F}_2\}$$

To Show this, I understand, we must show that $\mathcal{C} = \mathcal{R}$. How is that possible that my teacher said that it Is obvious that $\mathcal{C} \subseteq \mathcal{R}$? for instance, consider the following picture[image]

I don't find this inclusion obvious. Can someone help me?

Comment: im extremely confused :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, $\mathcal C\subseteq\mathcal R$. To show that $\mathcal C\subseteq\mathcal R$, we have to show that $A_1\times Y\in\mathcal R$ and $X\times A_2\in\mathcal R$. $A_1\times Y\in\mathcal R$ because $A_1\in\mathcal F_1$ and $Y\in\mathcal F_2$; $X\times A_2\in\mathcal R$ because $X\in\mathcal F_1$ and $A_2\in\mathcal F_2$. Since $\mathcal C\subseteq\mathcal R$, it follows that $\sigma(\mathcal C)\subseteq\sigma(\mathcal R)$.

Although $\mathcal R\not\subseteq\mathcal C$, we can show $\mathcal R\subseteq\sigma(\mathcal C)$ as follows: if $A_1\in\mathcal F_1$ and $A_2\in\mathcal F_2$, then$$A_1\times A_2=(A_1\times Y)\cap(X\times A_2)\in\sigma(\mathcal C).$$It follows that $\sigma(\mathcal R)\subseteq\sigma(\sigma(\mathcal C))=\sigma(\mathcal C)$.